# Search an image in a repository of images using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have a repository of 100k+ images (from non-direct sources - mostly web). Note that the images are of clothing items only (either with model wearing them or direct clothing item).

My aim is to click an image of any clothing item and search for the same in the repository that I mentioned. If an exact match is not available, I at least want closest matching images. Please help me understand how can I get the same in most accurate way possible (Speed/time not a concern, accuracy is the most imp parameter).

-------------x------------

What I have tried so far:

1. I first used the featurize function in the MicrosoftML library. This runs a pretrained model (RESNET101) on both my clicked & repository of images
2. The above function gives me 2050 features for both the images.
3. I found the euclidean distance between clicked & repository of images.
4. I showed the top 10 images with closest euclidean distance as an output.
5. Note that before even applying the euclidean distance, I have already applied the following manual filters to both the dataset - Filtered the brand and clothing type (shirt/pant/sweater etc.) for both the source and clicked images

However, the issue is that the accuracy is pathetically low (20%). Also, there are issues like - even if I click the image sideways, it will not match with the repository images or if there is a crease in the image, the algorithm takes it as a pattern.

For you guys to have a better idea of the code, PFB the featurization:

```
vec2dat <- rxFeaturize(
  data = fnddat,
  mlTransforms = list(
    loadImage(vars = list(Features = "Image")),
    resizeImage(vars = "Features", width = 224, height = 224),
    extractPixels(vars = "Features"),
    featurizeImage(var = "Features", dnnModel = "resnet101")   
  ))
```

PFB the euclidean distance code:

```
distance <- pdist(vec2dat[,-1],vecdat[,-1])
```

Any help/idea will be appreciated.

-------------------------Edit-------------------------

I think the question above seems a bit more broad. Let me break it down into parts:

1. Is there any other distances I could try to increase better apart from euclidean distance?
2. Out of 2049 features in RESNET101, are there any factors where I should give more/less weightage or is there any feature which I should ignore?
3. Is there any other pre-trained model which I can use (So far I have tried Alexnet & RESNET101)

Note that I do not want to set up a CNN in R, there is no scope of training a new model for me. I want to rely on pre-trained models available to us.

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO. This is more suited for [datascience stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @phiver-thanks for the suggestion. It is however, already present over there. I wanted some inputs from people who have already worked in this field in terms of code/ideas from this community.

Comment: You're basically asking us how to write a set up a convolutional neural network in R. You're better off working your way through a bunch of tutorials and maybe taking a MOOC or two. [CS 231n from Stanford](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/) is quite good although it uses Python instead. Also it is frowned upon to post the same question to different SE sites.